# Run Policy Based Management On Central Management Server with Code

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools, central-management-server, policy-based-management

I have a jump\terminal server to administer 100 SQL Servers and want to evaluate my locally created  policies across all the servers by using the Central Management Server but WITHOUT:

1. creating the policies on the target servers and
2. using the SSMS.

I need it to be run either with Powershell or T-SQL, doesn't really matter. I was trying to achieve this by iterating through a CSV file for each line holding the hostnames or by querying `msdb.dbo.sysmanagement_shared_registered_servers` system table but so far no luck. Any way to accomplish this feat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Invoke-PolicyEvaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-policyevaluation?view=sqlserver-ps) cmdlet to evaluate a policy stored as an XML file. This requires the SqlServer PowerShell module.